# web.config - 2nd URL rewrite rule not woking

Tags: iis, web-config

My wordpress has 2 rules of URL rewrite, this is the 1st rule:

```
<rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
    <match url="*"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
</rule>
```

This is the second rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

They both works independently. But if I combine both rules like below:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule>

        <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Only the first rule is working, the 2nd rule is ignored as if it does not exists. How to make the 2nd rule works together with 1st rule?

Comment: The rule of thumb is to put all redirection at top. To learn more of failing rules, use FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: What does the first rule do? I also have it in my WordPress installation and I have no idea where it came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect to https" enabled="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="wordpress" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url=" index.php" />
            </rule>
```

Best regards,

Sam